# How to deploy Q-learning model?

Tags: python, deployment, q-learning

I am trying to get familiar with Reinforcement Learning. I created a RL using Q-learning approach.

**Description of the problem**

1. I have a set of customers and each of them have the following features [price, category, cluster] - these customers represent the **state**
2. There are a range of 10 **actions** how much the price can be changed - example [0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9] - using some probabilities it is possible to identify the reward when the new prices are applied by using Q-function.
3. I was able to create and train the algorithm, but now suppose I want to use it in production. My idea is the following as an input would like to use the state [price, category, cluster] and as output I want to get the best action for this given customer. I also think it is important to update the model once you get the response from the customer, to give the new reward to the model.

I was trying to find some examples how to save and use the Q-learning function and how to use the update with the new data, but so far I do not see any examples.  Could anyone suggest some examples or some explanations on how it is possible to deploy and update the Q-learning model?

Comment: Randy, did you ever find a useful deployment approach?

Comment: @rmooney - in case of Q-learning, it is possible to save the final table and see the best option for a given scenario, however if the model is very big it might be challenging and in this case it is better to use the Deep Q-learning. I am not sure, if you know a better option or you are also facing similar issue

Comment: Thanks Randy.  I'm exploring options for a prototype and there's plenty of tutorials on grid worlds but not much info on productionizing RL.  My assumption is because it is simple and we just need to save the Q table and load it again at run time, while passing in the new environment data, though examples are lacking.